# authorization filter results in xml document has no style information

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

I am building a login application using JSF 2.2 and AWS. I got it working so far but now I am trying to implement an authorization filter using a servlet filter. Problem is whenever I enable the filter and try to test the page after uploading it to AWS elastic bean, I get an error **"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."** I searched for answers but I couldnt find anything concrete. I tried removing the filter but the problem persisted and it was that I had /*.xthml as the facelet url-pattern and I changed that to *.xhtml which seemed to fix it but when attempting to use the filter the same error appered.

Here's my Filter

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

public AuthenticationFilter() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    //User user = (session != null) ? session.getAttribute("username") : null;
    String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml";

    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null || loginRequest || resourceRequest) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
    }
    String uri = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();


    // session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    if ( uri.indexOf("/styles") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if( uri.indexOf("/images") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if( uri.indexOf("/js") > 0){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else {
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

And the web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF        Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>hello.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>test-param</param-name>
    <param-value>This parameter is for testing.</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/User/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have login.xhtml and register.xhtml directly in the WebContent folder which should have access and a welcome.xhtml page in a /User directory, which I am trying to limit the access to. I wasnt sure what else to include so if you require anything else I can provide it.

Comment: Are you sure the filter is the culprit? Also, why don't you have your resources root path based and referenced since there?

Comment: Im not entirely sure but as soon as I delete the filter and remove it from web.xml everything is working perfectly so Im guessing thats the problem. About the resources, I think that has been there since I created a web application template through the AWS SDK in Eclipse. I did not add it manually.

Comment: But you can manipulate the files as you wish, do you?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. I do have 1 issue showing up though: Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry myApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   myApp  P/myApp Classpath Dependency Validator Message. This is totally unrelated but i thought i'd post it.

Comment: Your filter URL pattern is illegal (just use `/User/*`) and you don't seem to understand how filters work as you're continuing to call  `doFilter()` and/or `sendRedirect()` multiple times in very same request. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: You are right I dont understand much, I just needed a login application for my own purposes. I checked out the link and I've done everything that was said in it but now the pages in /User are not restricted at all. There is no error displayed or anything it simply doesnt work.

Comment: I cant edit my previous comment -> I dont get whether it should be a .class file in the webinf folder or a java class in the source folder and why.